# Pseudoreplication in regression meta-analysis

Tags: regression, spatial

My understanding of spatial correlation in regression analyses is that the results are statistically invalid; however, I repeatedly see studies published in high-level academic journals that give no treatment (i.e., averaging values, mixed models, etc.) of spatial correlation. I understand this to be simple pseudoreplication.

My question is what are the risks of ignoring spatial correlation in large, spatially correlated datasets (i.e., many sites with many observations per site), and how are those risks felt? Would it induce shifts in the coefficients or tighter bounds on uncertainty? Does it depend on the size of the dataset?

Additional reading on this topic would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, having >1 non-independent point from a given site reduces the apparent uncertainty and generally inflates the likelihood of rejecting null hypotheses. It is a matter of pseudorepliction. Hurlbert 1984 is the classic reference and MUCH more has been written by many others on the same.